# Как запретить @Data генерировать методы? Lombok

Tags: java, lombok

Начал изучать Lombok. У меня есть класс, для которого идеально подходит аннотация `@Data`, вот только не надо, чтобы генерировались методы `hashCode()` и `equals()`. Есть ли какая-то возможность запретить `@Data` генерировать эти два метода? А то обидно получается такую портянку писать:

```
@ToString
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
```

Comment: вы уверены, что вам не нужны 2 этих метода? если они сгенерируются, вам от этого будет хуже?

Comment: @AndrewBystrov точно не нужны. Этот класс наследуется от абстрактного класса сущностей, в которой equals именно такой, какой нужен для работы с hibernate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В последней на данный момент версии Lombok 1.18.16 это невозможно.

Я пошарил по интернету и нашёл упоминание [тут](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/171). Но ишью давным давно закрыт, и вряд ли эти изменения добавят в следующих версиях.

Answer (score 0):

На данный момент, единственно возможным вариантом будет самому переопределить эти методы, но это имеет смысл только если, например, у вас появляется циклическая зависимость. Тоесть:

```
@Data
public class First {

    private long id;
    private Second second;
}
```

```
@Data
public class Second {

   private long id;
   private List<First> list;
}
```

Тогда, например, сгенерированный аннотацией `@Data` метод `toString()` будет рекурсивно ходить сначала к первому классу, оттуда ко второму, оттуда снова к первому, и так до тех пор, пока не упает с какой-нибудь ошибкой. А иначе, не вижу смысла их переопределять)
Но аннотация @Data делает конструктор со всеми полями, поэтому, чтобы конструктор так же был без аргументов, допишите одну аннотацию (итого две)

Comment: Но было бы забавно, если бы Lombok позволял наследовать аннотации и таким способом пилить свои собственные, включающие например только те, что тебе нужны, как это сделано в Jackson -> ```@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @JacksonAnnotationsInside
    @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
    @JsonPropertyOrder({ "name", "id", "dateCreated" })
    public @interface CustomAnnotation {}```